# Php script when i click on button or image

Tags: php, sql, onclick

I have this code `

### Lessons List

```
                    $sqlessons = 'SELECT * FROM lessons ';
                    $lessons = $mysqli->query($sqlessons);  
                    while ($row=$lessons->fetch_assoc()) 
                    {
                        echo "<li>$row[lesson_name] : <span>$row[lesson_description]</span></li>";?>
                        <form action="script.php" method="get">
                            <input type="submit" value="Add this lesson now!">
                        </form>

                    <?php } ?>
                    </p>
                    </ul>`
```

this code presents a list of lessons with **a button below of every lesson**.
I want to add to this button a funtion that adds to my database : 
$user_id ( i have that loaded in session )
$lesson_id (i have that only inside the 'while')

so if I click the button on Lesson1 (lesson_id =1) and I am the user Nick D (user_id=2) then the script will add a line to my database table usersVSlessons : 
10,1,2 (the 10 is a random foreign key of the table).

I think you get what I want to do :P 
Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried getting your <form> elements out of the loop?

Comment: This way I ll have only one button and a list of lessons

Comment: https://www.techrepublic.com/article/handling-multiple-submits-in-a-single-form-with-php/

Answer (score 0):

Place both user_id & lesson_id in input type hidden, get values onclick submit buttom & then make an ajax call to store data in db.

*(you can either generate random no. in javascript or you can also use php to generate random value & input type to hidden place it)*